# Xcode:Cannot find test bundle myAppUITests.xctest

Tags: ios, xctest, xcode-ui-testing, xcode7.3

I'm trying to execute UI tests (written with XCTest) from the command line but I'm getting this error:

> Cannot find test bundle myAppUITests.xctest

Where is the bundle for the UI test located?

Comment: Have you built the test first?

Comment: I can run the unit test but not the UI test

Comment: What commands are you using to build and run the UI test?